# Multiple laravel mappings, one side wont work

Tags: php, laravel

Hello guys I have made couple of classes with mappings as follows:

```
class Like extends Model

/**
 * Returns like's author
 * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsTo
 */
public function owner(){
    return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
}

/**
 * Returns tweet
 * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsTo
 */
public function tweet(){
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Tweet');
}

Class Tweet extends Model


/**
 * Returns tweet's author
 * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsTo
 */
public function owner(){
    return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
}

/**
 * Returns tweet's likes
 * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasMany
 */
public function likes(){
    return $this->hasMany('App\Like');
}

Class User extends Authenticatable
use Notifiable;

/**
 * The attributes that are mass assignable.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $fillable = [
    'email', 'password', 'www', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'status'
];

/**
 * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $hidden = [
    'password',
];


/**
 * Returns user's tweets
 * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasMany
 */
public function tweets(){
    return $this->hasMany('App\Tweet');
}

/**
 * Returns user's likes
 * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasMany
 */
public function likes(){
    return $this->hasMany('App\Like');
}
```

Now the problem is that two of my maping are not working. In Like model 'owner' method returns null, although its should return one record, 'tweet' method for the other hand works as expected.

In Tweet model the 'owner' method also returns null. All other methods are working as expected. I can't find where I have made mistake, and cannot rly understand why tweet method from Like model is working and owner is not....

Maybe Migrations find might be helpfull

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('likes', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->integer('tweet_id');
        $table->integer('user_id');
        $table->string('status');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}


 public function up()
{
    Schema::create('tweets', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->integer('user_id');
        $table->string('content');
        $table->string('score');
        $table->string('views');
        $table->string('status');
        $table->timestamps();

 public function up()
{
    Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('email')->unique();
        $table->string('password',60);
        $table->string('www');
        $table->string('first_name');
        $table->string('last_name');
        $table->string('status');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both your **Tweet** & **Like** Models have `owner()` as their `belongsTo()` relationship method. Which is fine, but you'll have to specify the foreign key as second argument:

```
/**
 * Returns like's author
 * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsTo
 */
public function owner()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\User', 'user_id');
}
```

Laravel docs:

> Eloquent determines the default foreign key name by examining the ***name of the relationship method*** and suffixing the method name with `_id`.

Answer (score 0):

You have to specify the foreign key:

```
Schema::table('tweets', function ($table) {
    $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned();
    $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users');
});
```